# iOS 7 UIScrollView doesn't scroll when presented as modal view controller, works fine otherwise

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a storyboard in which I have a view controller, (InfoViewController) in which I have an UIScrollView with some labels, uitextviews, etc. this is all created in IB, no code has been written at all. The only thing that is left for me to do is to set the content size, which I do as following:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(screenRect.size.width, 600)];
[self.scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
}
```

Whenever I make this view the entry point of my app, it works perfectly. I can see my view, the content size is set, the background color is being set to green.

Now it comes, I created another view controller, and this view controller is now my entry point of the app. I added a button in there, and on this button I did a "modal segue" to the earlier mentioned Info View Controller.

When I now run my app, I press this button, my Info View Controller shows up. The green background color is being set, but it's impossible to scroll. So the code is being executed (otherwise the background color couldn't been green, in the storyboard it's just plain white) but somehow whenever I use this "modal segue", the scroll functionality gets lost.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using Autolayout? If so have you set constrains on the UIScrollView? Have you logged the frame size of the UIScrollView to see if it's correct?

Comment: Yep, I do use that.

Yes, I have constraints.

I have logged the frame in both scenarions, in both cases this is the result:

frame = origin=(x=0, y=20) size=(width=320, height=548)

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert a UIView into the scroll view...
Set the UIView with top, bottom, leading and trailing space to super view to 0.

Then insert everything into the UIView rather than into the ScrollView

Then modify the constraint height of the inner UIView instead of the contentsize of the scroll view, it works with iOS7